# Tips for designing pages for third world countries with slow internet

Tags: jquery, asp.net, css, web, responsive-design

I'll be developing a site in .Net where much of the site's exposure will come from the Middle East. However, it will get most of its exposure from America.

I want to develop a responsive website, however, in most middle eastern countries the internet connections are terribly slow, so I'm faced with a dilemma.

Are there some tips in creating a very light responsive site? I'm unsure where to begin.

Comment: All images in ONE sprite. ONE. I don't care how many images you use, they go in a sprite. Cache All The Things. Serve lower quality images with the option of viewing higher quality ones should the user decide that's something they want. Limit the amount of JavaScript you require the user to be exposed to. If you're really worried about page size, don't make the layout require javascript, as my experience says most of them run with JS disabled.

Comment: oh no! no JavaScript? That's going to be hard to refrain from :( Thank you for the advice! i was thinking of perhaps having two sites and allow the user to decide on higher or lower quality. I just know it will be much more work. What do you think?

Comment: It's not "No javascript", it's "don't make the page rely on javscript". Forms should be able to be handled without ajax. Button clicks should have less and less effects. Don't slideToggle things, etc. There's nothing wrong with it being beautiful, but avoid the flashy. With regards to the higher/lower quality portion; it'll really only come to the js/css, because the server's load doesn't need to change, so some simple conditionals of file inclusion should be enough here. Please don't use slideshows, stay away from heavy animating, processing speed is also a factor.

Comment: Ah yes, I see. Thank you for your great response. I feel like I have something to start with now.

Answer (score 1):

There's a lot of small things you can do that together can speed up your website. Things like putting style sheet references at the top, javascript scripts at the bottom..There's a good list here at Yahoo Developers site:

[Best Practices for Speeding Up Your Web Site](http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html)